# Selecting all items in listview from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

I have a ListView on my WPF window, and I have a button that is suppose to select all. First how do you get the button to do select all the items in the listview.

Secondly, I need my ViewModel to then go through all the selected items. How do I obtain this information in my ViewModel?

I've read you can do this with IsSelected property but has a bug, where the local property overrides the binding property so if it has already been selected before then it doesn't appear to be selected again - or something like that. It seems convoluted. [The blog that looks into this problem](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/09/)

Then I've read this blog [Data binding to selected items](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html)  which also seems very convoluted.

I would like to know if it has to be that convoluted and that those examples are the only way forward.

XAML:

```
        <ListView Name="sources_ListView" Grid.RowSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sources}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="290" Header="Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OriginalPath}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Type">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Select All" Name="selectAllSources_Button" Margin="3" />
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Deselect All" Name="deselectAllSources_Button" Margin="3" />
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Remove Selected" Name="removeSelected_Button" Margin="3" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RV1987 Thanks for your answer, that was definately a big part of it. However for the rest of it I found this blog which detailed exactly how to do it with source code. Definitely a worth while read.

[Bad Entropy Blog](http://grokys.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iv.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Attach a handler on your button -

```
<Button Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Call `SelectAll` method on your ListView instance -

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   sources_ListView.SelectAll();
}
```

Secondly, in case all the items are selected on View, in that case `ItemsSource` will always be equal to the `SelectedItems`. So, simply iterate over the ItemsSource i.e. `Sources` in your case.

Comment: Why not `MVVM`? We can handle view specific things in code behind but bussiness related logic should always be there in ViewModel. Isn't it?

Comment: An MVVM purist will tell you that the view should have NO code behind (beyond the constructor)

Comment: From `MSDN` - `Code-behind may contain UI logic code that implements visual behavior. You should not put any logic code in the view that you need to unit test.`

Comment: @RV1987 I agree that view-specific code may be present in code behind. However I have a question: How do you handle the situation where the ViewModel needs to manipulate the selection? I mean, selecting or deselecting items according to some logic defined in the ViewModel?

Comment: @HighCore - Yeah me too in favour of MVVM pattern but this answer is only in reference to OP's question. He want to go through all the selected items after selecting all items for which ItemsSource will always be equal to the selectedItems. There may be other ways too for solving this but i suggested only the easy way(with non-violation of MVVM)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a behavior to allow a property in a control to be bound to a property of a collection of items, in a way that:

- If you change the property in the control, all of the items are updated.
- If you change the property in a item, if all the items have the same property the control will reflect it. If not, the property of the control will be given a fallback value (like null).

You can use this to bind a CheckBox.IsChecked to a IsSelected property of type in a collection of elements of this type. 
I suggested it to a guy who wanted to do something similar to what you want, but with a DataGrid. You can take a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540566/check-box-in-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp-application/13541741#13541741).

Answer (score 0):

I created an attached behavior quite a while ago that handles this. It allows you to bind the list of SelectedItems to an observable collection on the View Model and handles shuttling changes back and forth.

Using attached behaviors is the preferred approach for extending functionality to existing controls (instead of subclassing the control) that would otherwise require extensive view logic.

I wouldn't say that you should ALWAYS use this approach over placing logic in the view. But it's a simple way to capture behavior for easy re-use.