# How to bind an object's boolean property to a CheckBox's IsChecked property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, checkbox

I have an ObservableCollection of objects that have a boolean property.

In the GUI, I have a CheckBox from which I want to bind its IsChecked property to each object's boolean property.

Is it possible using XAML only? How?

**I want to do it only with binding cause biding is faster than loop**

Comment: You have single checkbox or list of checkboxes you want to bind?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding path}>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding yourBoolPropertyName, Mode = TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This will create list of checkboxes that will bind to your collection. Of course, you must properly set paths for binding.

Comment: The checkbox located outside of the listbox. I need to bind it to all the listitems (objects) all together in one click\time.

Comment: U can bind to some bool property, setter can look like this: set { foreach (var i in items) i.prop = true; }...

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool property on your ViewModel which will loop through all `Objects` of your ObservableCollection to see property is true for every object -

```
public bool AllTrue
{
   get
   {
      return Objects.All(o => o.Selected);
   }
}
```

Here `Objects` is instance of your `ObservableCollection` and `Selected` is a bool property in an object.

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AllTrue}"/>
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I want to check the checkbox and change some bool propery in all the object of a list to True and the same way for unchecked with false.

I want to do it only with binding cause biding is faster than loop

Answer (score 0):

I have created a behavior to allow a property in a control to be bound to a property of a collection of items, in a way that:

- If you change the property in the control, all of the items are updated.
- If you change the property in a item, if all the items have the same property the control will reflect it. If not, the property of the control will be given a fallback value (like null).

  ```
  public class CollectionPropertyBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
  {

  private IEnumerable<ValueProxy> proxies;
  private bool syncking;

  public string SourcePropertyPath
  {
      get { return (string)GetValue(SourcePropertyPathProperty); }
      set { SetValue(SourcePropertyPathProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SourcePropertyPathProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SourcePropertyPath", typeof(string), typeof(CollectionPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

  public string CollectionPropertyPath
  {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CollectionPropertyPathProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CollectionPropertyPathProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionPropertyPathProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("CollectionPropertyPath", typeof(string), typeof(CollectionPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


  private IEnumerable<object> Items { get { return  this.ItemsSource == null ? null : this.ItemsSource.OfType<object>(); } }
  public IEnumerable ItemsSource
  {
      get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CollectionPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourceChanged));


  private object Value
  {
      get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
  }
  private static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(CollectionPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, ValueChanged));


  public object DefaultValue
  {
      get { return (object)GetValue(DefaultValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(DefaultValueProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultValue", typeof(object), typeof(CollectionPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));



  private static void ValueChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
      var element = sender as CollectionPropertyBehavior;
      if (element == null || element.ItemsSource == null) return;

      element.UpdateCollection();
  }

  private static void ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
      var element = sender as CollectionPropertyBehavior;
      if (element == null || element.ItemsSource == null) return;
      element.ItemsSourceChanged();
  }

  private void ItemsSourceChanged()
  {
      this.proxies = null;

      if (this.Items == null || !this.Items.Any() || this.CollectionPropertyPath == null) return;

      // Cria os proxies
      this.proxies = this.Items.Select(o =>
      {
          var proxy = new ValueProxy();
          proxy.Bind(o, this.CollectionPropertyPath);
          proxy.ValueChanged += (s, e) => this.UpdateSource();
          return proxy;
      }).ToArray();

      this.UpdateSource();
  }

  private void UpdateSource()
  {
      if (this.syncking) return;

      // Atualiza o valor 
      using (new SynckingScope(this))
      {
          object value = this.proxies.First().Value;
          foreach (var proxy in this.proxies.Skip(1))
          {
              value = object.Equals(proxy.Value, value) ? value : this.DefaultValue;
          }

          this.Value = value;
      }
  }

  private void UpdateCollection()
  {
      // Se o valor estiver mudando em função da atualização de algum 
      // elemento da coleção, não faz nada
      if (this.syncking) return;

      using (new SynckingScope(this))
      {
          // Atualiza todos os elementos da coleção,
          // atrávés dos proxies
          if (this.proxies != null)
              foreach (var proxy in this.proxies)
                  proxy.Value = this.Value;
      }
  }

  protected override void OnAttached()
  {
      base.OnAttached();


      // Bind da propriedade do objeto fonte para o behavior
      var binding = new Binding(this.SourcePropertyPath);
      binding.Source = this.AssociatedObject;
      binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching()
  {
      base.OnDetaching();

      // Limpa o binding de value para a propriedade do objeto associado
      this.ClearValue(ValueProperty);
  }

  internal class SynckingScope : IDisposable
  {
      private readonly CollectionPropertyBehavior parent;

      public SynckingScope(CollectionPropertyBehavior parent)
      {
          this.parent = parent;
          this.parent.syncking = true;
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          this.parent.syncking = false;
      }
  }

  internal class ValueProxy : DependencyObject
  {
      public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

      public object Value
      {
          get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
          set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(ValueProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnValueChanged));


      private static void OnValueChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
      {
          var element = sender as ValueProxy;
          if (element == null || element.ValueChanged == null) return;

          element.ValueChanged(element, EventArgs.Empty);
      }

      public void Bind(object source, string path)
      {
          // Realiza o binding de value com o objeto desejado
          var binding = new Binding(path);
          binding.Source = source;
          binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

          BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
      }
  }
  }
  ```

You can use it like this:

```
<CheckBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:CollectionPropertyBehavior CollectionPropertyPath="MyBooleanProperty" SourcePropertyPath="IsChecked" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionInViewModel}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

It doesn't support collection changes yet (just collection swap), but I believe it can be easily modified to to that. If you want to use it out of the box, you can just add a handler to the CollectionChanged event of your ObservableCollection so it will trigger the ItemsSource update:

```
observableCollection.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemsSource);
```

I've posted another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540566/check-box-in-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp-application/13541741#13541741).